# Wait for subscribe to finish its job inside while loop (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable

I have a while loop, and inside the while loop i have two subscribes. How can i wait for them to finish to continue using the while loop?

```
this.counter = 1;
array[0] = 3;
while(this.counter <= array[0])
    {
        console.log("WHILE: "+this.counter);
        this.ms.getPopular(this.tv, this.counter).subscribe(val => {
            this.afstore.collection("matches").doc(this.id).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val2: any) => {
                console.log(this.counter);
                if(this.counter == array[0])
                {
                    return;
                }
                //console.log("YES");
                this.counter++;
            });
        });

        this.counter++;
    }
```

My current output is

```
WHILE: 1
WHILE: 2
WHILE: 3
4
5
6
```

But the output i would want to get is

```
WHILE: 1
1
2
3
```

With the `this.counter++` not even being needed inside the while loop. With out that inside the while itself, it just runs infinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, have a recursive function.

```
this.counter = 0;
this.max = 3;

function subscribe() {
  
  this.ms.getPopular(this.tv, this.counter).subscribe(val => {
    this.afstore.collection("matches").doc(this.id).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val2: any) => {

      if (this.counter == this.max) {
        return;
      } else {
        this.counter++;
        this.subscribe();
      }

    });
  });
}
```